# [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "Items". Expected array, got Promise

Tags: vue.js, promise, axios

I am new to the entire node technology stack and trying to improve myself by taking on a project.  At this point I have had moderate success (possibly by chance), but I am currently stuck.  My client side is using 'axios, vue, vue-router, vuetify' and a few others.  The server side code is 'axios, bluebird, sequelize and sqlite3'.

My issue is as follows, I am trying to populate a 'v-data-table' by making the following function call:

```
<v-data-table
:headers="task_headers"
:items="getTasks(props.item.upgrade_id)"
hide-actions
item-key="task_id"
>
```

My function looks as follows:

```
  methods: {
      async getTasks (id) {
      try {
        console.log('JAC in getTask value of id is: ', id)
        this.tasks = await TasksService.show(id)
        console.log('JAC value of this.tasks is typeof: ', typeof this.tasks)
        console.log('JAC value of this.tasks values are: ', Object.values(this.tasks))
        console.log('JAC value of this.tasks keys are: ', Object.keys(this.tasks))
        return this.tasks.data
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
   }
```

My debug messages produce the following output:

```
    JAC value of this.tasks is typeof:  object

    JAC value of this.tasks values are:  
    (6) [Array(9), 200, "OK", {…}, {…}, XMLHttpRequest]0: 


   JAC value of this.tasks keys are:  
   (6) ["data", "status", "statusText", "headers", "config", "request"]
```

this.tasks values Array of 9 is carrying the data returned from the db that I need, but I do not understand how to return the data.  I have many other service calls to the backend which are working just fine. v-data-table is expecting an array and I do not understand what I am missing to get this to work.

Comment: Your element should pull your data from the `data` attribute on the component, not a method

Comment: `async` means the function will always return a Promise.

Comment: Thanks @Derek  I have 'tasks: [ ]' defined in the data attribute ...

        `export default {
            data () {
            return {
            tasks: [],`

Comment: @jac then you should use that in `:items`, not the method

Comment: @jac I run into similar issue regarding `v-select` having the items as `async`. If you haven't found a solution I will post my answer.

Answer (score -1):

async getTasks (id) { <- remove async, and return an array

You are expecting in v-data-table an array and with the async property, it will return a promise therefore you got that error.

If you dont want to remove that, you can do something like this.

```
getTasks(props.item.upgrade_id).then((data) => {
this.tasks = data;
})

<v-data-table
:headers="task_headers" 
:items="tasks"<- updated this line and no longer it will return a promisa
hide-actions
item-key="task_id"
>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @HectorTinajero !   The issue is that my v-data-table needs to be populated based on the click of a parent v-data-table.  So the population of the inside v-data-table needs to be responsive.  The parent table has 2000 records and potentially 200,000 children.  So I ONLY want the child table to populate if the row is clicked (hence the function call).  Your suggestion has gotten me really close in that I now have an object (which contains and array) as opposed to a promise.

Comment: `getTasks` calls a service, it **has** to have asynchronisity to it either through the `async` keyword or by returning a `Promise`.